# Suspending and resuming Grand Central Dispatch thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I am using Grand Central Dispatch to run a process in background. I want know how can i suspend, resume and stop that background thread. I have tried

```
dispatch_suspend(background_thread);
dispatch_resume(background_thread);
```

but these functions doesn't help me, it keeps on running. Please someone help me.

Comment: If what to implement such a way than better you use NSOperation instead of GCD. With NSOperation you can achieve this more easily and this will also save you from many multithreading complexity and problems.

Comment: but why the above functions of GCD are not working?

Comment: @CRDave, Can you please give me an example of NSOperationQueue. I have tried this
NSOperation *Queue = [NSOperation new];
NSInvocationOperation *op = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc]initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(somefun) object:@"hello"];
[Queue addOperation:op];

Now i want to suspend op on a button click, now please let me know what function i should use to suspend the op

Comment: So is there any other method of suspending the running thread?

Comment: or is there any method to stop GCD thread?

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have some confusion.  Direct manipulation of threads is not part of the GCD API.  The GCD object you normally manipulate is a queue, not a thread.  You put blocks in a queue, and GCD runs those blocks on any thread it wants.<sup>1</sup>

Furthermore, [the `dispatch_suspend` man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man3/dispatch_suspend.3.html) says this:

> The dispatch framework always checks the suspension status before executing a block, but such changes never affect a block during execution (non-preemptive).

In other words, GCD will not suspend a queue while the queue is running a block.  It will only suspend a queue while the queue is in between blocks.

I'm not aware of any public API that lets you stop a thread without cooperation from the function running on that thread (for example by setting a flag that is checked periodically on that thread).

If possible, you should break up your long-running computation so that you can work on it incrementally in a succession of blocks.  Then you can suspend the queue that runs those blocks.

---

Footnote 1.  Except the main queue.  If you put a block on the main queue, GCD will only run that block on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing a concurrent processing model, where different processes can be suspended and resumed. This is often achieved using threads, or in some cases coroutines.

GCD uses a different model, one of partially ordered blocks where each block is sequentially executed without pre-emption, suspension or resumption directly supported.

GCD semaphores do exist, and may suit your needs, however creating general cooperating concurrent threads with them is not the goal of GCD. Otherwise look at a thread based solution using `NSThread` or even Posix threads.

Take a look at Apple's [Migrating Away from Threads](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html) to see if your model is suited to migration to GCD, but not all models are.